# Red sguigglies in TypeScript file for all third party libraries

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code doesn't like my third party libraries (it gives them red sguigglies when they compile just fine). I see this:

[image]

So the dependencies here that have red sguigglies are:

- KnockoutJS
- Xml2Json
- jQuery

How do I get Visual Studio Code to like my third party libraries (remove the red sguigglies)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio Code can take advantage of type definition files (.d.ts files) to make sense of Javascript libraries. The easiest and fastest way to get these files into your project is to place your cursor on a piece of unrecognized (underlined) code until you see the IntelliSense lightbulb. Click it and choose "download type definition xxxxx.d.ts." VS Code will download the relevant .d.ts file and place it in a new typings folder within your project.

Alternatively, you can browse and choose .d.ts files manually by doing the following steps:

1. Visit https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped and find the project folder for Knockout, jQuery, Xml2Json (under X2js), or another needed library.
2. Download the .d.ts file only and place it in the same folder as your local .js file.
3. Restart Visual Studio Code and open your project's javascript folder file by choosing [File > Open folder...]. Visual Studio Code will automatically pick up on your .d.ts file, and the squigglies in your .js file will be banished!

There's a lot more you can do to manage and play with type definition files, but this should solve the immediate concern. Happy coding!

Sources used and additional reading:

- Personal testing with Jquery.d.ts, Knockout.d.ts, and Visual Studio Code v.0.10.8 running on Windows 10 and Mac OS X
- https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript

Comment: Thanks. I don't have a local.js file but it still worked except for xml2json. At the bottom of the d.ts file it has `declare var X2JS: IX2JS;`. It has no export. I'm wondering if I change it to `declare var xml2json` and `export xml2json` or something similar.